# errors when sending a SMS message using textbelt.com

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I face errors when I try to send a SMS message from textbelt.com ...

this is my code :

> ```
> > import requests
> > 
> > resp= requests.post('https://textbelt.com/text', {
> >         'phone' : '+21276355555',
> >         'message': 'Hello sidi khelkhel ... goodmorninggg wolh ..LBOUGHAZZ .\n..I love you wolh ',
> >         'key': 'textbelt'
> >     })
> > 
> > print(resp.json())
> ```

I expect to send a message for that number and this is the errors that I got :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\HP
> PAVIL\Desktop\python\python mini projects\scheduleSendingMsg.py", line
> 9, in 
> print(resp.json())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\HP PAVIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
> line 900, in json
> return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\HP PAVIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json_*init*_.py",
> line 346, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\HP PAVIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py",
> line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\HP
> PAVIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\json\decoder.py",
> line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)

Comment: What is `resp.text`? Are you getting any error codes from the server?

Comment: resp.text isn't in my code!
why should I have errors from the server ?

Comment: I ran your code. The server returned an error, but Python didn't  raise any exceptions. Can you provide some more information on how you're running this code?

Comment: like what this information?

I ran the program like all the programs that I created...

after some research...I think the problem is in textbelt.com ...I guess they have some issues while providing free SMS to users